# how to find min and max number of intervening items between first multiple occurences of values in a data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a factor vector called Categories with 47 levels

```
Categories = as.factor(sort(make.unique(rep(letters, length.out = 47), sep='')))

[1] a  a1 b  b1 c  c1 d  d1 e  e1 f  f1 g  g1 h  h1 i  i1 j  j1 k  k1 l  l1 m  m1 n  n1 o  o1 p  p1 q  q1 r  r1 s  s1 t 
[40] t1 u  u1 v  w  x  y  z 
47 Levels: a a1 b b1 c c1 d d1 e e1 f f1 g g1 h h1 i i1 j j1 k k1 l l1 m m1 n n1 o o1 p p1 q q1 r r1 s s1 t t1 u u1 ... z
```

I have another vector called cat with 9 of those levels

```
cat = Categories[c(7,42,43,24,45,26,35,6,15)]
[1] d  u1 v  l1 x  m1 r  c1 h 
47 Levels: a a1 b b1 c c1 d d1 e e1 f f1 g g1 h h1 i i1 j j1 k k1 l l1 m m1 n n1 o o1 p p1 q q1 r r1 s s1 t t1 u u1 ... z
```

I also have a dataframe My_Data with 36 rows. One of the columns in the dataframe has multiple occurences of the values from cat

```
My_Data = data.frame(name = make.unique(rep(c(1:10,LETTERS), length.out = 36), sep=''), cat = sample(rep(cat,4),36,replace = FALSE), position = 0)

    name cat position
1     1   v        0
2     2   r        0
3     3   h        0
4     4  m1        0
5     5   h        0
6     6  u1        0
7     7  l1        0
8     8   h        0
9     9  u1        0
10   10   x        0
11    A   x        0
12    B   v        0
13    C   d        0
14    D  c1        0
15    E   r        0
16    F   v        0
17    G  l1        0
18    H   d        0
19    I  l1        0
20    J  c1        0
21    K  u1        0
22    L   x        0
23    M   v        0
24    N   d        0
25    O  l1        0
26    P  m1        0
27    Q   r        0
28    R  m1        0
29    S   h        0
30    T  m1        0
31    U  c1        0
32    V   d        0
33    W   r        0
34    X   x        0
35    Y  c1        0
36    Z  u1        0
```

Using the code below, I can populate the position column given above to reflect the number of occurence of the value in the cat column:

```
transform(My_Data, position = ave(as.character(cat), cat, FUN = seq_along))
```

The first 15 rows of the dataframe My_Data would look like:

```
    name cat position
1     1   v        1
2     2   r        1
3     3   h        1
4     4  m1        1
5     5   h        2
6     6  u1        1
7     7  l1        1
8     8   h        3
9     9  u1        2
10   10   x        1
11    A   x        2
12    B   v        2
13    C   d        1
14    D  c1        1
15    E   r        2
```

Now I want to calculate the min. and max. number of intervening items between any 2 consecutive occurences of the same value of the cat column.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, here's one option:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Data
Categories = as.factor(sort(make.unique(rep(letters, length.out = 47), sep='')))  
cat = Categories[c(7,42,43,24,45,26,35,6,15)]
# Set a seed for reproducibility
set.seed(5)
My_Data = data.frame(name = make.unique(rep(c(1:10,LETTERS), length.out = 36), sep=''), 
                     cat = sample(rep(cat,4),36,replace = FALSE), 
                     position = 0)
```

The code below summarises to give the minimum and maximum number of intervening rows for each level of `cat`.

```
# Summarise to give min and max number rows between each occurrence
My_Data %>%
  mutate(row=1:n()) %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>% 
  summarise(min.diff=min(diff(row)-1, na.rm=TRUE),
            max.diff=max(diff(row)-1, na.rm=TRUE))
```

> ```
>      cat min.diff max.diff
>   <fctr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
> 1     c1        4        6
> 2      d        1       16
> 3      h        1       16
> 4     l1        0       13
> 5     m1        0       12
> 6      r        5       15
> 7     u1        2        7
> 8      v        1       16
> 9      x        6       12
> ```

If you want to mark the number of intervening rows in the original data frame: The code below adds a column to the original data frame to give the number of intervening rows since the last occurrence of a given level of `cat`.

```
# Add column with intervening number of rows between each occurrence in cat
My_Data %>%
  mutate(row=1:n()) %>% 
  group_by(cat) %>% 
  mutate(diff=c(NA,diff(row)-1)) %>%
  select(-row)
```

> ```
>      name    cat position  diff
>    <fctr> <fctr>    <dbl> <dbl>
>  1      1     c1        0    NA
>  2      2     m1        0    NA
>  3      3      x        0    NA
>  4      4      d        0    NA
>  5      5     l1        0    NA
>  6      6     l1        0     0
>  7      7      r        0    NA
>  8      8     c1        0     6
>  9      9      h        0    NA
> 10     10      v        0    NA
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidy solution using `lag()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

# create data frame
set.seed(1)
Categories <- as.factor(sort(make.unique(rep(letters, length.out = 47), sep='')))
cat <- Categories[c(7,42,43,24,45,26,35,6,15)]
My_Data <- data.frame(
  name = make.unique(rep(c(1:10,LETTERS), length.out = 36), sep=''), 
  cat = sample(rep(cat,4),36,replace = FALSE), 
  position = 0
)

# solution
My_Data %>%
  mutate(row = 1:n()) %>%
  group_by(cat) %>%
  mutate(inter = row - lag(row) - 1) %>%
  summarize(min_inter = min(inter, na.rm = T), max_inter = max(inter, na.rm = T))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 9 x 3
     cat min_inter max_inter
  <fctr>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     c1         0        10
2      d         4        11
3      h         0         8
4     l1         0         6
5     m1         1         3
6      r         0        16
7     u1         2         5
8      v         1        23
9      x         6        15
```